# how to merge array of objects in angular?

Tags: arrays, angular, object

i want to merge these two arrays based on "sequence". If sequence number is same in both array ,then i want to merge that 2 object. i don't know how to do it. can anyone help me?

````
dynamicArray =[
{id:null,sequence:  1, fromTime: "5:00",toTime:"6:00"},
{id:null,sequence:  2, fromTime: "8:00",toTime:"9:00"}]; ```

```contactDetails = [

{id:null, sequence:  1, contactName: "jen",mobileCode:"2",mobile:"556"},
{id:null, sequence:  1, contactName: "dali",mobileCode:"",mobile:"557"}]; ```

**the output should be **

``` result =[
{id:null,sequence:  1, fromTime: "5:00",toTime:"6:00",contactName: "jen",mobileCode:"2",mobile:"556"},

{id:null,sequence:  1, fromTime: "5:00",toTime:"6:00",contactName: "dali",mobileCode:"",mobile:"557"},

{id:null,sequence:  2, fromTime: "8:00",toTime:"9:00"}]```
````

Comment: if not same then just push that object into array like sequence 2

Answer (score 0):

I created a working code snippet

```js
var dynamicArray = [
  {id:null,sequence:  1, fromTime: "5:00",toTime:"6:00"},
  {id:null,sequence:  2, fromTime: "8:00",toTime:"9:00"},
];

var contactDetails = [
  {id:null, sequence:  1, contactName: "jen", mobileCode:"2", mobile:"556"},
  {id:null, sequence:  1, contactName: "dali", mobileCode:"", mobile:"557"},
];

var mergedArray = dynamicArray.map(dynamic => {
  var mergedWithContact = contactDetails.filter(contact => contact.sequence === dynamic.sequence).map(contact => ({ ...dynamic, ...contact}));
  return mergedWithContact.length > 0 ? mergedWithContact : dynamic;
}).flat();

console.log(mergedArray);
```